# Programa en C++, Menú que le faltan funciones locales (No globales)

Tags: c++

Simular un sistema de creación de un inventario, venta, consulta y actualización de un producto.

Menú.

1. crear inventario por teclado(si no se creo desde un archivo, el programa debe solicitar el código del producto, nombre, precio unitario y cantidad, así creamos el inventario del único producto).
2. consultar (solicitar el código de producto, si existe imprimir los datos del producto. Siempre que haya creado (teclado o archivo)).
3. venta o facturación (solicitamos el código, si existe la cantidad deseada, si la cantidad solicitada existe o esta esta disponible facturamos y actualizamos el inventario).
4. Salir y grabar el inventario.

Lo que le falta son funciones pero no globales, ese es el problema que tengo con mi código, que ahora faltan las funciones pero no se como hacerlo funciones locales.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>//libreria c++ (cin, cout)

using namespace std;
int main()
{
int opcion, codigo, codigo1 ,precio, cantidad, cantidad1;//declaracion de variables
string producto;
ofstream archisalida; //Paso 2, objeto de la clase ofstream que se utilisara para remplazar el 
cout
archisalida.open("producto.dat"); //Paso 3, Se esta creando un archivo para grabar en las 
carpeta donde esta el codigo
do
{ //interaccion con el menu por teclado
    system("CLS");
    cout<<("sistema de inventario\n")<<endl;
    cout<<"1.- crear producto (ingrese el solicitar el codigo del producto, nombre, precio 
unitario y cantidad)"<<endl;
    cout<<"2.- consultar."<<endl;
    cout<<"3.- venta o facturacion"<<endl;
    cout<<"4.- Salir y grabar"<<endl;
    cout<<"Cual es la opcion a desear\n"<<endl;
    cin>>opcion;
    switch(opcion)
    {
        case 1:// creando el producto 
            system("cls");
            cout<<"Ingrese el nombre del producto\n"<<endl;
            cin>>producto;
            cout<<"Ingrese el codigo del prodcuto\n"<<endl;
            cin>>codigo;
            cout<<"Ingrese el precio del producto\n"<<endl;
            cin>>precio;
            cout<<"Ingrese la cantidad del prodcuto\n"<<endl;
            cin>>cantidad;
            system("pause");
            break;
        case 2://consultando producto 
            system("cls");
            cout<<"imgrese el codigo del prodcuto\n"  <<endl;
            cin>>codigo1;
            if(codigo1==codigo) {
            cout<<"su prodcuto es:\t"<<producto <<endl;
            cout<<"su codigo es:\t"<<codigo <<endl;
            cout<<"su precio es:\t"<<precio <<endl;
            cout<<"su cantidad es:\t"<<cantidad <<endl;
            }
            else {
            cout<<("usted ingreso el codigo incorrecto:")<<endl;                    
            }
            system("pause");
            break;
        case 3://conprando producto y facturando
                system("cls");
            cout<<"imgrese el codigo del prodcuto\n"  <<endl;
            cin>>codigo1;
            if(codigo1==codigo) {
            cout<<"codigo correcto\n" <<endl;
         }
            else {
            cout<<("lo sentimos no podemos continuar")<<endl;                   
            }
            
            cout<<"imgrese la cantidad que desea del prodcuto\n"  <<endl;
            cin>>cantidad1;
            if(cantidad<cantidad1)  {
            cout<<"el prodcuto no se puede vender\n" <<endl;
            }
            else {
            cantidad-=cantidad1;
            precio*=cantidad;
             cout<<"el producto se vendio exitosamente"<<endl;
             cout<<"factura del producto "<<endl;
             cout<<"producto comprado:\t"<<producto <<endl;
            cout<<"codigo del producto:\t"<<codigo <<endl;
            cout<<"precio a pagar:\t"<<precio<<endl;
            cout<<"cantidad comprada del producto:\t"<<cantidad <<endl;
            }
             
             cout<<"se a actualizado la lista del producto"<<endl;
            
            
            system("pause");
            break;
        
            
        case 4: cout<<"cerrar y grabar "; // Esta grabando en el archivo el mensaje
                archisalida<<"factura del producto "<<endl;
                archisalida<<"producto comprado:\t"<<producto <<endl;
                archisalida<<"codigo del producto:\t"<<codigo <<endl;
                archisalida<<"precio a pagar:$\t"<<precio<<endl;
                archisalida<<"cantidad comprada del producto:\t"<<cantidad <<endl;
                archisalida.close();    // se cierra el archivo
                 system("cls");
            break;      
            
        default:  cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t Opcion no valida";
         
               system("pause");
                  break;
    }
}while(opcion!=4); //mientras la opcion sea distinta o menor a 4
cout<<"gracias por su tiempo..."<<endl; 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿ Que se supone que son las `funciones pero no globales` esas ?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 1):

En el switch, en el case 2 (donde consultas el producto), debieras introducir  dentro de un for la condicional de preguntar si el código introducido por el usuario es igual a alguno de los códigos registrados anteriormente porque de la manera que lo estás haciendo sólo comparas el valor que introduce el usuario con el último código registrado, lo que provoca que el código ingresado por el usuario pueda estar entre los códigos registrados pero puede no ser el último registrado pr lo que si no es el último no imprimirá los datos del producto correspondiente al código ingresado y dirá que el código ingresado no es correcto. Creo que deberías cambiar ese else por ¨El código introducido no concuerda con ningún producto registrado¨ o algo parecido.

Ejemplo:

```
    case 2://consultando producto 
        system("cls");
        cout<<"imgrese el codigo del prodcuto\n"  <<endl;
        cin>>codigo1;
        
        /* Debes crear un contador para saber la cantidad de códigos que 
        se ha registrado. Usaré de ejemplo cantCod */
        
        for(int i=0; i<cantCod ++i){
        // Los códigos ingresados los puedes guardar en un arreglo
            if(codigo1 == arreglo_codigo[i]) {
                cout<<"su prodcuto es:\t"<<producto <<endl;
                cout<<"su codigo es:\t"<<codigo <<endl;
                cout<<"su precio es:\t"<<precio <<endl;
                cout<<"su cantidad es:\t"<<cantidad <<endl;

                /* Si el código es igual al valor del arreglo muestra
                   los valores y terminas el for ya que no es necesario 
                   recorrer todos los valores si el que buscas no está al 
                   final 
                */
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
        cout<<¨El código introducido no concuerda con ningún producto
               registrado¨<<endl;                    
        }
        system("pause");
        break;
```

En el case 3 debes revisar que decir porque creo que pasa lo mismo que en el 2.

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).